# how to get associative array from string

Tags: php

I have one string like:-

```
$attributes = "id=1 username=puneet mobile=0987778987 u_id=232";
```

Now, I want to get it in following associative array format:-

```
$attributes{'id' => 1, 'username' => puneet, 'mobile' => 0987778987, 'u_id' => 232}
```

Note:- These all values are separated by space only. Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you to do it with a regular expression:

```
$str = "id=1 username=puneet mobile=0987778987 u_id=232";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all( '/(?P<key>\w+)\=(?P<val>[^\s]+)/', $str, $matches );
$res = array_combine( $matches['key'], $matches['val'] );
```

working example in [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/y4e-m0c)

Answer (score 3):

```
$final_array = array();

$kvps = explode(' ', $attributes);
foreach( $kvps as $kvp ) {
    list($k, $v) = explode('=', $kvp);
    $final_array[$k] = $v;
}
```

Comment: is there any function available to acheive this task?? I am looking for function rather than loop

Comment: @Puneet Write a function that take `$attributes` as a parameter and returns `$final_array`

Answer (score 2):

```
$temp1 = explode(" ", $attributes);
foreach($temp1 as $v){
 $temp2 = explode("=", $v);
 $attributes[$temp2[0]] = $temp2[1];
}
```

[EXPLODE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

this code will solve your problem.

```
<?php
$attributes = "id=1 username=puneet mobile=0987778987 u_id=232";
$a = explode ( ' ', $attributes) ;
$new_array = array();
foreach($a as $value)
{
    //echo $value;
    $pos = strrpos($value, "=");
    $key = substr($value, 0, $pos);
    $value = substr($value, $pos+1);

    $new_array[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($new_array);
?>
```

out put of this code is

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => puneet [mobile] => 0987778987 [u_id] => 232 )
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to split this string two times

1. divide with space
2. divide with `'='`